# How to move the mouse every 3 minutes?

Tags: autoit

I am trying to move the mouse every 2 minutes so that the session doesn't time out. But despite no syntax errors, it doesn't work.

My code:

```
global $x = 1
global $y = 1
If Mod(@MIN, 3) = 0 Then
    MouseMove (global $x, global $y, 2)
    global $x++
    global $y++
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its more usefull to perform a callback function for timed calls.

```
AdlibRegister('_MouseMove', 2000*60)   ; calls the function every 2000*60 ms
OnAutoItExitRegister('_UnRegister')    ; unregister the callback function when the script ends

Func _MouseMove()
    Local $aPos = MouseGetPos()
    ; move 1px right and back after a short brake - so that your interface can detect the movement
    MouseMove($aPos[0]+1, $aPos[1])
    Sleep(50)
    MouseMove($aPos[0], $aPos[1])
EndFunc

Func _UnRegister()
    AdlibUnRegister('_MouseMove')
EndFunc
```

Btw.: Increasing values with AutoIt works so

```
$x += 1
```

Edit:
I'm not sure, if you want 2 or 3 minutes (you've written both). So you can change it in the time parameter in AdlibRegister(). The interval must given in ms.

Answer (score 1):

The following script move the mouse one pixel every 3 minutes, preventing the session time out, with minimal impact on the computer usage.

```
HotKeySet( "{ESC}" , "Sair")

While True
    MouseMove(MouseGetPos(0)+1,MouseGetPos(1))
    Sleep(180000)
    MouseMove(MouseGetPos(0)-1,MouseGetPos(1))
    Sleep(180000)
WEnd


Func Sair()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

Comment: Please explain why this code solves the problem, as code-only answers are of little value and are considered bad answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your script in SciTE you should see the following error message:

[image]

You need the `global` keyword only when declaring a variable. When using a variable you have to ommit the `global` keyword. You should change your script accordingly and it might work then.